# error Access to XMLHttpRequest at file from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I work on asp.net core application 2.2 I face issue when download file from  server path as below

```
DeliverySystem:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pno.mydataz.com:7072/api/DeliverySys/Download?fileName=DeliveryGeneration_Input.xlsx' from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

what I try is :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Download")]
public IActionResult Download(string filename)
{
   
    if (filename == null)
        return Content("filename not present");

   
    var path = Path.Combine(
                   GetFilesDownload, filename);
 

    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
    
    return File(memory, "text/plain", Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

I Get error when download static excel file from server
so why this error display and how to solve issue ?

**updated Post**

I set core policy on my start up application

```
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseCors(builder =>
             builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Client_URL"].ToString())
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             );
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

front end is angular 8 as below :

```
DownloadFile(filePath: string, fileType: string): Observable<any> {

  let fileExtension = fileType;
  let input = filePath;

return this.http.get(this.url +'DeliverySys/Download'+ "?fileName=" + input, {
 
      responseType: 'blob',
      observe: 'response'
  })
      .pipe(
          map((res: any) => {
              return new Blob([res.body], { type: fileExtension });
          })
      );
}
```

link generated as below :

```
https://pn.mydataz.com:7072/api/DeliverySys/Download?fileName=DeliveryGeneration_Input.xlsx
```

and this link not on

```
current client_url on app settings not  
https://pno.mydataz.com:7072/

current client url on app settings is 
  "Client_URL": "http://localhost:4200"
```

request header is :

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,ar;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ
Connection: keep-alive
Host: pn.mydataz.com:7072
Origin: https://pno.mydataz.com:7071
Referer: https://pno.mydataz.com:7071/
```

Comment: Did you set the cors policy in startup.cs like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware-1)?

Comment: What's your scheme? Did you send the request in another project? I mean that it's not supposed to have cors error in the same program.

Comment: yes i set core policy

Comment: 1) I don't think you should be calling `app.UseCors()` twice. 2) What value have you configured in `ApplicationSettings:Client_URL`?

Comment: @ahmedbarbary How about using `builder.AllowAnyOrigin()` instead to rule out the possibility of  an error Origin ?

Comment: @ahmedbarbary I'm afraid you need to show us how you send request to this api to start the download. I tested in my side and I found that even I don't add cors policy in the start up, when I using `<a href="https://localhost:44395/download">click</a>` in my spa, it can still start the download. Could you pls add more details on the frontend app?

Comment: can you tell me what data you need to give i will send to you as soon as possible

Comment: @ahmedbarbary Hi, I've showed my code snippet, you can compare it with yours. And if you find to useless to you, pls feel free to show the code that sending http request for calling the download api. Thanks for your response : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls allow me to post my test information here to show more details well.

First this is my controller and file structure, and when I call the link `https://localhost:44395/download` in the browser, it can pop up the download window.

[image]

and here I set the CORS policy in my startup file like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseCors(builder =>
             builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

And I create a SPA with an ajax call to this url, this function :

```
  $(function() {
        initPage7();
  });
  function initPage7() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44395/download",
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {}
    })
  }
```

And My test result:

[image]